# How to fix this? c++ compiler set up

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, g++, installation

I installed gcc via xcode but I am getting this error when trying to compile the file:

```
 sanjay$ g++ main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Fraction::Fraction(int, int)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
      BinaryMathTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
      BasicTest()    in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator/=(Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator-=(Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator*=(Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator--(int)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator--()", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator+=(Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator++(int)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "Fraction::operator++()", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator/(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      BinaryMathTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator==(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator>=(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator>(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator<=(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      MathAssignTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
      BinaryMathTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
      BasicTest()    in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator<(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator-(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      BinaryMathTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator*(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      BinaryMathTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator!=(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      RelationTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator+(Fraction const&, Fraction const&)", referenced from:
      BinaryMathTest()     in cck2LKpO.o
  "operator>>(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Fraction&)", referenced from:
      BasicTest()    in cck2LKpO.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do i fix this?
I am pretty sure my g++ compiler has been set up properly as it works for files in a different folders. PLease help me out with this..I am a beginner in this language and am trying my best to understand.

Comment: The module containing the Fraction class  must also be compiled and linked with main.cpp to form an executable. The linker is searching for the symbols listed - they are not present in main.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the cpp file containing the Fraction class to the command line. Something like this

```
g++ main.cpp Fraction.cpp
```

Hope that helps. :)